# Create a for-loop with eval()?

Tags: php, eval

Before I start, I know it is bad code!

However, can I create a for-loop with `eval()`?

The background is that I created a class that loads a template-file and then replaces certain placeholders with values that I store in an array, e.g. if the template looks like this

```
<b>[;;title]</b>
```

and the placeholer-array looks like this

```
array (1) { ["title"] => "The Title" }
```

this code:

```
loadTemplate("the_template", $the_array_with_placeholders);
```

would return this:

**The Title**

I would like to create a for-loop within the template but, however, when creating the template, I don't know how often I need a certain part.

So I would like to store a number as a placeholder (`$placeholder_array = array("steps" => 4);` and then use that in the template like

```
eval ( "for ($x = 0; $x < [;;steps]; $x++) { echo $x; }" );
```

But it does not work. Is there a solution to that? Again, I know it's bad code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, see the following example:

```php
<?php
$string = "for (\$x = 0; \$x < [;;steps]; \$x++) { echo \$x; }";
$eval_string = str_replace("[;;steps]", 5, $string);
eval($eval_string);
```

Outputs:

> 01234

I guess you just missed the escaping of the variables (`\$`).

Comment: Ah, many thanks, will try now! That must be it.